# How to avoid LazyInitializationException when using WebSockets in Spring?

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, websocket, stomp

Any advices how to avoid the infamous LazyInitializationException in the following setup (working with spring and hibernate) :

```
@MessageMapping("/activate/foo")
@SendToUser("/queue/result")
public Result doit(Integer fooId) {
    Foo foo = fooService.load(fooId); // via hibernate
    result = ... // accessing foo outside a hibernate transaction
                 // therefore a LazyInitializationException is thrown
    return result;
}
```

What to do?

1. Annotate doit() with @Transactional?
2. Calculate result inside a method annotated with @Transactional?
3. Manually doing the stuff that OpenSessionInViewFilter is doing for servlet requests?
4. Utilizing some type of "ready to use" filters or interceptors for WebSockets in Spring (which one, how, examples?)
5. Tomcat WebSocket Filter?

Right now I'm voting for 3, but it looks so uncool... ;-)

Comment: If you are getting a Lazy Initialisation error, then your code for calculating `result` must be trying to access something which hasn't been loaded. So the big question is: does the calculation **need** to access the unloaded data? If so, then yes, you need to make either `doit` transactional. 2 is not going to help you if `doit` is not transactional because the Entity will be detached when it comes back from the `load`. So 1 is your best bet.

Comment: I'm struggling with similar issues. I don't think doIt should be Transactional. Your fooService should be. But you need some kind of openSessionInView style filter for WebSocket messaging. 

I've tried writing my own, based on ChannelInterceptor, but no luck so far